# .htaccess gives an error

Tags: html, .htaccess

I have searched on google but could not find any answer on this

```
Redirect 301 */home/nl /Hotel/home
Redirect 301 */home/en /Hotel/en/home
Redirect 301 */home/du /Hotel/du/home
Redirect 301 */home/fa /Hotel/fa/home
```

This is my htaccess, It need to detect to whole url before the /home url but this is not working only on the left part of it not the right, that works correctly I have tried * and $ before the /home none works.

Comment: What server system are you using?

Comment: html, do you mean that?

Comment: HTML is a markup language.  I mean are you using Apache, Microsoft Internet Server, what?

Comment: You say it "gives you an error".  Care to share with us what that error might be?

Comment: @Majenko it gives an error (I think) because it does not work, sorry for that

Comment: Have you tried looking in any log files your mystery system may be generating to see if there are any error or status messages in there?

Comment: @Majenko unfortunately it doesn't

Comment: Without knowing what kind of web server you have it's impossible to really help you.  It could be that you're simply using a web server that doesn't support `.htaccess`, or that doesn't have the required modules installed.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Apache, with mod_rewrite, you can try using a full regexp to rewrite the path:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/home/([^/]+)/(.*) /Hotel/$1/home/$2 [R]
```

(note: untested)

Comment: sorry this doesn't work, I don't think I have Apache